# OpenLayers 3 - Opacity slider in layer tree does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, openlayers-3

I included a layer tree according to http://www.acuriousanimal.com/thebookofopenlayers3/chapter02_03_layer_groups.html and http://jsfiddle.net/joshuadickerson92/mtwbs2dg/ (JSFiddle - cannot post more than 2 links due to insufficient reputation) in my Openlayers 3 map.

I cannot get the opacity slider to work. Moving it from right to left and vice versa has no effect on the opacity of the layers at all, regardless of these parameters: `data-slider-min='0' data-slider-max='1' data-slider-step='0.1'`

This bit

```
$('input.opacity').slider().on('slide', function (ev) {
    var layername = $(this).closest('li').data('layerid');
    var layer = findBy(map.getLayerGroup(), 'name', layername);

    layer.setOpacity(ev.value);
});
```

seems to be skipped over when checking the page in Firefox's debugger tool.

I've been searching for solutions for days now, but still couldn't find anything. Any help appreciated!

JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/kidalex/j34xzaa3/5/

---

Update: I added [this](http://www.acuriousanimal.com/thebookofopenlayers3/scripts/3b87a9e8.vendor.js) chunk of JS code, and now it works! Updated fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/kidalex/j34xzaa3/5/
Now I'm going to investigate which ones of those 8914 lines of (tidied up) code are the cause for that.

Answer (score 0):

Try publishing your whole code so we can help better.

More probably your issue is related to javascript than to OL3, because of this I can't give you a concrete solution.

Ensure your `$('input.opacity').slider().on('slide', function (ev) {...` function returns a good `ev.value` when you move the slider.

Check too your `findBy` function works fine a the `layername` variable is getting the right value.

Use your browser debugger or simply the console to check all that.

Cheers.

Comment: Thanks Eric; I think there was some code missing, though. See my edited post - with JS code added it works!

Comment: aaaa... that file contains all the vendors JS code concatenated and minimized. Don't use that file on your app. This is the source code for the examples: https://github.com/acanimal/thebookofopenlayers3 and this is the "compiled" code https://github.com/acanimal/thebookofopenlayers3/tree/gh-pages. I think what you need is include the jQuery "seiyria-bootstrap-slider" plugin (both its JS and CSS files).